# Getting error message "Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:" when Trying to get GPS coordinates on iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I'm getting the following error message when trying to get GPS coordinates on iOS using (Swift, SwiftUI), based on the following tutorial:

`The error message`

```
Thread 1: "Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:"
```

`The URL of the tutorial`

```
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-read-the-users-location-using-locationbutton
```

My question is:

- Is the tutorial incomplete?
- Do I have to add some additional code to try out this app?
- What does the error message mean?

`The code` (taken from the tutorial) is:

```
import SwiftUI

import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        location = locations.first?.coordinate
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if let location = locationManager.location {
                Text("Your location: \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)")
            }
            
            LocationButton {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add method `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Error handling
        print("Error requesting location")
    }` below `didUpdateLocations` method

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by Kishan Bhatiya, the following addition to the code fixes it (by providing error handling):

```
import SwiftUI

import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        location = locations.first?.coordinate
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Error handling
        print("Error requesting location")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if let location = locationManager.location {
                Text("Your location: \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)")
            }
            
            LocationButton {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```